# How to force LLVM to unparse the AST?

Tags: c++, llvm

I have an input file (.ll) which I'd like to have parsed by LLVM, thus generating the in-memory representation of the program, and then it should be unparsed and dumped to stdout, but purely from the generated AST. I succeed partly. LLVM parses the program and dumps the module out to stdout. However the formatting of the original source code is preserved. That makes be think that LLVM did not really unparse the AST to dump the module, but instead it could be that LLVM stores the text representation along with the in-memory AST, and in case no changes were made, prefers to dump this textual representation, which is not what I want.

```
  std::cout << "Reading IR ...\n";

  LLVMContext &Context = getGlobalContext();
  SMDiagnostic Err;
  Module *Mod = ParseIRFile(argv[1], Err, Context);

  if (!Mod) {
    std::cerr << "Problems reading IR\n";
    return 1;
  }

  Mod->dump();
```

My question is: Why is the formatting of the  original source code preserved when dumping out the module, and is there a way to make LLVM drop the text representation of the program and have it in fact unparse the AST?

Comment: Just a theory, but some tools and designed to preserve everything they can for "round-tripping" because it's often the right thing to do. That doesn't mean the generation didn't happen from the AST - I don't have experience with it, but I'd guess it either means there's more in the AST than you see or the output side refers back to the original source as well as the AST. Either way, to ensure the output contains exactly what you want, one way would be to duplicate the AST first - copying only those nodes and details you want and breaking any link back to the source.

Comment: Probably not a good way, though, as it assumes your knowledge of which AST nodes you want is not only perfect, but also that it will stay perfect - new AST node types with new LLVM versions may easily be unnoticed.

Comment: Interesting question! I never noticed dumping a module preserves formatting, could you attach an example of how it looks like? Also, just a note: while an AST is possibly used when parsing the IR, the LLVM IR itself is not an AST - there's no tree hiding in a `Module`.

Comment: And you are right! There ARE actually some minor changes in the formatting, like indenting by 2 spaces as compared to 1 space in the input. A quick overview looked THAT close to the input that I was convinced nothing actually happened. But the code above indeed unparses the IR and, at least it seems, no formatting is stored along with the IR (in-memory).

Comment: @Frank Glad I could help. I added my comment as an answer instead so it would be more visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never noticed dumping a module preserves formatting, you should check it again. From what I know, it should not happen.

Also, while an AST is possibly used when parsing the IR, the LLVM IR itself is not an AST - there's no tree hiding in a Module.

Answer (score 3):

IR parser *does not* preserve the formatting. There is no point in doing this. It's just an IR writer which is used to dump the module to stdout is precisely the same as one used to dump to .ll file. So, you always have the same formatting in dumps compared to input .ll file unless the latter is somehow hand-generated.